# PHP multi_query returns Error: Unknown column 'Type' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv, alter-table, mysqli-multi-query

I wrote my very first **PHP** script which **imports a csv file** into a database, **treats it** and **exports it** again into another csv file.

The problem is that even though I can check de database in phpMyAdmin and the column "Type" do exist, when I run the script it says

*Error: Unknown column 'Type' in 'field list'*

As it didn't actually created the column. I really don't understand what's happening there, and I hope someone can give me some light on it. I know my code isn't very good and it could be done in a much simpler way but I will live optimization for the next step, once my code actually works :P

It has two parts, the import&treat:

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
$sep = ","; 
$fp = fopen('./test.csv', 'w+');     
$servidor="localhost"; $usuario="root";     
$contrasena="";     
$db=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$contrasena); 
$Type="a"; mysqli_select_db($db, "test");

$sql="DROP TABLE test;"; 
$sql.="CREATE TABLE test (Country varchar(55), Code varchar(55), Rate varchar(55), Currency varchar(55), Indicator varchar(55), EffectiveDate varchar(55));"; 
$sql.="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'http://localhost/test2.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;"; 
$sql.="ALTER TABLE test ADD Type VARCHAR(55) NULL;";

if (mysqli_multi_query($db,$sql)) {  
do   {   }  
while (mysqli_next_result($db)); }

mysqli_close($db);
```

And the exporting, which i do separately because my knowledge wasn't so good.

```
$db2=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$contrasena);
mysqli_select_db($db2, "test");
$sql1="SELECT Country, Code, Rate, EffectiveDate, Type FROM test LIMIT 100;";
$datos1=mysqli_query($db2, $sql1)
    or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($db2));

while($datos2 = mysqli_fetch_array($datos1)) {
$linea = $datos2['Country'].$sep.$datos2['Code'].$sep.$datos2['Rate'].$sep.$datos2['EffectiveDate'].$sep.$datos2['Type'].$sep;
fwrite($fp,$linea);
}
fclose($fp);

mysqli_close($db2);

echo "GOOD JOB!";
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I somehow doubt that MySQL can read data directly via http. My guess is that this query failes and the following query doesn't get executed.

Comment: Almost missed your adding the column there. I think you cannot load via HTTP is the issue. This statement fails, so the next statement (ALTER...) is not executed

Comment: @beiller , I don't really understand how can the loading via http fail if, when you enter phpmyadmin, the table exists and it's properly imported.
When I use the same script avoiding the ALTER TABLE and just exporting Country, Code, Rate and EffectiveDate it works, it exports the csv just fine. Only when I try to create the column it returns the error.

Comment: Try using backticks ` to surround the word `Type`, I know its not a reserved keyword but I am somewhat at a loss then.

Comment: Tried, same error :( don't know what else to try

Comment: Can you try doing the query directly in MySQL?